# How to pull data from database and store them into arrays in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am learning Android development. I have an IOU table that has name and amount. So, after multiple entries into the DB table, you would have something like this:

```
name1 50
name2 25
name1 10
name3 60
```

...   ...

My question is, what is the best way to pull the entries from the table and sort them as an array in an Adroid application.

For example, Array1[] name1 = [50, 10, ...] where 50 and 10 are the amount associated with name1 in the DB.

I cannot just use `SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = name1` because the names will change and it will be increasing. I heard from this SO question:
[How to store arrays in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122949/how-to-store-arrays-in-a-database)
that dynamically generating table is not a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY name
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY amount
```

That is, you don't need a WHERE clause if you want all of the rows. And the ORDER BY clause can do the sorting for you.

**However**: Are you sure that you **need** to pull all the data into an array -- especially if the database can do the sorting that you need? One alternative would be to open a cursor, and then do whatever processing you need one row at a time.

**EDIT**: Another example (based on your comment; I have not tested this):

```
SELECT name, SUM(amount) FROM table GROUP BY name ORDER BY name
```

will give you one row for each unique name in the database, with the sum of each amount associated with that user. For the example you posted above, this would result in the following rows:

```
name1 60  // The sum of the two rows that have name="name1"
name2 25
name3 60
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. Can you expand on the cursor a little bit more? For example, if I have the DB sorted via name, and name1 has 100 entries which totaled to $100. I can use a cursor, process each row, adds up the amount (should total to 100) and display that to the user? Every time the app starts, it would run this query? I will need to do it for all "names" which means I have to parse through the entire DB row every time and present a list of name1 - totalAmount, name2 - totalAmount...

Comment: @Yko: SQLite can do the summing for you too; see my edit. And you can certainly have your program do this query when it starts up. For more details, I suggest you check out the tutorial that niky suggested (http://www.screaming-penguin.com/node/7742) or this one: http://souptonuts.sourceforge.net/readme_sqlite_tutorial.html , as well as the Android developer tutorials.